# Bottom sheet not rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet

I was creating a bottom sheet using the library "gorham/bottom-sheet". For some reason the close icon is not visible. Also i am not able to drag and slide the bottom sheet too. Here's the code:

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import UpArrowIcon from "../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_up_arrow.svg"
import DownArrowIcon from "../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_down_arrow.svg"
import RightArrowIcon from "../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_right_arrow.svg"
import CloseIcon from "../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_close_icon.svg"

type SpaceBottomSheetProps = {
    onClose: () => void;
}

const SpaceBottomSheet = ({ onClose }: SpaceBottomSheetProps) => {
    // ref
    const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

    const [expandedItem, setExpandedItem] = useState(null);

    // variables
    const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%'], []);


    // callbacks
    const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
        console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
    }, []);

    const closeBottomSheet = () => {
        if (bottomSheetRef.current) {
            bottomSheetRef.current.close();
            onClose();
        }
    };

    const data = [
        { label: '2D Test' },
        { label: '2D Testing 2' },
        { label: '2D Testing 3' },
        { label: '2D Testing 1' },
        { label: '2D Testzaffar' },
        { label: '2D TestZaffar' },
    ];

    const expandedData = [
        { label: 'Dashboard' },
        { label: 'List of Subspaces' },
        { label: 'View Space Details' },
        { label: 'Create Subspace' },
    ];

    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        const isExpanded = expandedItem === index;

        const handlePress = () => {
            LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
            setExpandedItem(isExpanded ? null : index);
        };

        return (
            <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
                    <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.label}>{item.label}</Text>
                        {isExpanded ? (
                            <UpArrowIcon width={12} height={10} style={styles.arrowIcon} />
                        ) : (
                            <DownArrowIcon width={12} height={10} style={styles.arrowIcon} />
                        )}
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {isExpanded && (
                    <FlatList
                        data={expandedData}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                            <>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.rowContainer}>
                                    <View style={styles.row}>
                                        <Text style={styles.rowLabel}>{item.label}</Text>
                                        <RightArrowIcon style={styles.rowArrowIcon} />
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                {item.label === 'List of Subspaces' && <View style={styles.separator} />}
                            </>
                        )}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.label}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        );
    };


    // renders
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <BottomSheet
                ref={bottomSheetRef}
                index={1}
                snapPoints={snapPoints}
                onChange={handleSheetChanges}
            >
                <View style={styles.bottomSheet}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => closeBottomSheet()} style={styles.closeIcon}>
                        <CloseIcon width={14.65} height={14.65} /> //HERE'S THE CLOSE ICON
                    </TouchableOpacity> 
                    <View style={styles.header}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>Truminds</Text>
                        <Text style={[styles.create, { color: expandedItem !== null ? '#0F8D48' : '#4D4D4D' }]}>
                            + Create Subspace
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.separator} />
                    <FlatList
                        style={[styles.list, { flexGrow: 1 }]}
                        data={data}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.label}
                    />
                </View>
            </BottomSheet>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingHorizontal: 0,
        paddingTop: 28,
        paddingBottom: 12,
    },
    itemContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginBottom: 17,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: '800',
        color: '#4D4D4D',
        //fontFamily: fontFamily.theme.EXTRA_BOLD
    },
    create: {
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: '600',
    },
    bottomSheet: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
        borderTopRightRadius: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        marginTop: -20,
    },
    separator: {
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#ddd',
        marginVertical: 10,
    },
    list: {
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    listItem: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },
    labelContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingBottom: 3,
        paddingTop: 3,
    },
    label: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '600',
        color: '#4D4D4D',
    },
    arrowIcon: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        color: '#000000',
    },
    closeIcon: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
    },
    rowContainer: {
        paddingHorizontal: 4,
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },
    row: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    rowLabel: {
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: '500',
        color: '#4D4D4D',
    },
    rowArrowIcon: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        color: '#000000',
    },
});

export default SpaceBottomSheet;
```

I am using svg files for the icons. What could be the possible reasons for the closeIcon not being rendered?

[Here's the image of the bottom sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ3YS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in `container` style which is the padding from `react-navigation` SafeAreaView

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {
        ....
        paddingBottom: 34 <-- Add this one -->
    }
})
```